# PHP log in form error

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication

I am following a video on YouTube on how to add a log in form on to a website, `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oSCuEtxRK8`

At 8:37, when he clicks on username or password, nothing happens, no error message but my error message comes up. Here is my code

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)
{

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die("Couldn't connect!";
mysql_select_db("phplogin") or die ("Couldn't find db");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM "); users WHERE username='$username'");

$numrows = mysqal_num_rows($query);

echo $numrows;

}
else
    die("Please enter username and a password!");
?>
```

Error message I get is

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Hamza\login.php on line 9
```

I used localhost:8080 instead of just localhost

```
http://localhost:8080/Hamza/login.php
```

Would this be a problem?

Comment: The syntax highlighting shows where your error is.

Comment: `die("Couldn't connect!"` should be `die("Couldn't connect!")` — the hint is in the error `login.php on line 9`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM "); users`

Comment: Start of with a new tutorial, mysql_ is deprecated and shouldn't be used any more! Have a look on mysqli_ or PDO

Comment: You have so many error's in your code! SOLUTION: DELETE it and start new

Comment: @baao, already more, not just `deprecated`, it removed now.

Comment: Have a look at code academy. Far better than out of date amateur YouTube vids. http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-StaFQ/0/1?curriculum_id=5124ef4c78d510dd89003eb8

Comment: This is a debugging question and not a technical question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure even a professional cleaning firm could clean up this mess :)
See updated code below, you have a couple of typo's which has been commented and replaced with a new line.

When learning from Youtube, pause sometimes and go over your code, try to understand how it works. Seems like you're just rushing to copy all of it and never even looks at the code.

Also read the error messages, they're there for a reason.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Hamza\login.php on line 9
```

**Unexpected ';' on line 9** - take a look at line 9, you've forgot to close the die() bracket, so the ; was unexpected.

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)
{

//$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die("Couldn't connect!";
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root")or die("Couldn't connect!");
mysql_select_db("phplogin") or die ("Couldn't find db");

//$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM "); users WHERE username='$username'");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

//$numrows = mysqal_num_rows($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

echo $numrows;

}
else
    die("Please enter username and a password!");
?>
```

**A few (very important) side notes, which you must learn sooner or later:**

- Passwords should not be stored as plain text in your database (or any other place for that matter).
  If using PHP 5.5.0 or later you can use the php function `password_hash()` which creates a very secure hash. You can then use `password_verify()` for the login function.
  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php for more info.
- Older hashing algorithms like md5 and sha1 should not be used for storing passwords. They are unsafe and can easily be cracked.
  If you can't use `password_verify()`, please also read up on salts. Salts can make the hashes even more secure by adding a unique salt to every hashed password.
- Your current code only does a database query for the username. Needless to say, you should also check submitted password before logging in the user :)
- Input sanitizing. It's important to sanitize all user input to avoid security breaches. Think of all users as hackers who are constantly attacking your website. Read the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php) for a few quick tips, but I recommend you to google and read more about input sanitizing.
- Don't use mysql_* functions. You'd be better of starting right at mysqli (syntax is almost identical to mysql) or PDO. Read up on them and learn them, as you will need to at some point. (mysql_* is deprecated and will stop working in a future PHP version)
- Both MySQLi and PDO supports prepared statements. It basically means the database is preparing and optimizing the query in advance, then binding all values into the query right before execution. This will also avoid SQL injections to some degree because the query is already prepared by the time you're binding the values (which may be user input) to the query.

Comment: *"I'm not sure even a professional cleaning firm could clean up this mess"* - lol good one ;)

Comment: Add the fact that the OP is storing plain text passwords (and shouldn't be), along with not sanitizing inputs, and should be using prepared statements and links to `password_hash()` and I'll upvote ;)

Comment: Haha, glad you liked the comment. I figured I should give him some slack at first, but you're right; the post has been updated with a few tips. Thanks for feedback fred -ii- :) Let me know if there's anything crucial I forgot/should add

Comment: I'd say that covers pretty well everything. +1, I'm a man of my words ;)

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated! Added a warning about md5/sha1 hashes as well, which are still regularly used unfortunately :)

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, both of those were good and served a purpose at some point. However, they can still be used for other things besides password storage, so it's not a total fiasco. Let's just hope that the "question of time", won't apply anytime soon for `password_hash()`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, they are often quick and efficient for many things. My comment was a bit misleading, I meant I still see it used for password hashes which I consider bad in 2014 :)

Comment: No, it's ok; I understood what you meant. Yeah, some still do and it's probably due to the fact that they may not know about its vulnerabilities (till it's too late). Even I get surprised at the stuff I learn about here on Stack and other forums.

Answer (score 0):

The query needs to be corrected:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
```

That was pretty basic. Understand you are new so You need to do your code review more carefully look at the error logs more closely.

Comment: There are more errors.